# Average of row in MySql table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have ordinary sql table in MySql database. I have approximately 150 columns and I would like  to compute average of rows of this table. I am going to do this in c#.

So I would like to do somethig like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

for(int i=1; i<=rowCount;i++){
string query="SELECT AVG(Column1, Column2, ... Column150) FROM mytable WHERE ID="+i;
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, connect);

// and here I will save partial results to array
}
}
```

Is something like this posible?
Thx

Comment: why dont you try and check?

Comment: Do you mean you want the average of the values stored in columns 1 to 150 of a given row?

Comment: You might be better to avoid running loads of queries from your `for` loop and do all of this in one SQL query. It will be much more efficient for a lot of rows

Comment: @RashmiPandit exactly. I was trying to perform such SQL command on my mysql server, but I am getting this error :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`RT2`) FROM `reflextime` WHERE `ID` = 1' at line 1

Comment: @geedubb and Can you please suggest  how to  build such query that will return average for every row of my table? I am not advanced user of sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work this way. Average is a function above a column, not above a row.

Here, you can try something like:

```
SELECT (Column1 + Column2 + ... Column150)/150.0 FROM mytable WHERE ID="+i
```

Comment: (I realised one issue - the division would be by integer, fixed now)